# How do I model or simulate a "squishy" object compressed inside a container?

Tags: modeling, soft-body

I'm looking for a way to create a model of an object squeezed into and compressed by a tight spherical enclosure surrounding it (think a plush toy stuffed inside a hollow ball). I don't want to simply flatten the parts of the object that are touching the enclosure; I also want other areas to bulge out as if the volume of the object is being displaced by the compression. How can I do this, either using modeling tools directly or through a soft body or other physics simulation?

Note that I am only interested in the final compressed state of the object, not an animated sequence showing how it gets compressed (although I don't mind using an animated simulation if it gets me to my end goal).

I'm also open to suggestions for other software tools that would make it easier to do this.

Comment: The way I'd do it is to add a volumetric soft body sim to the object and animate the contain scaling down around it to the correct size. Unfortunately blender does not currently support volume preservation in soft bodies, and I'm not sure of any other easily available software that does.

Comment: Check Houdini 17. I think with Vellum it could be possible.